# What is the value of $\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)^{\alpha-1} (1-s)^{\alpha} \rm{d}s$?, where $0<t<1$ and $0 <\alpha \leq 1$.

Tags: integration, gamma-function, fractional-calculus

I saw the value of this integral in one research article. They wrote $-\frac{1}{\Gamma{(\alpha+1)}\Gamma{(\alpha)}}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)^{\alpha-1} (1-s)^{\alpha} \rm{d}s = -\frac{t^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)} + \frac{t^{\alpha+1}}{\Gamma(\alpha+2)}$. I don't know how they got this value for that integral value. I know how to get value for this type of integral $\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\Gamma{(\alpha+1)}\Gamma{(\alpha)}}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)^{\alpha-1} s^{\alpha} \rm{d}s = \frac{t^{2\alpha}}{\Gamma(2\alpha+1)}$.
Let $u=s/t$. Then $\frac{1}{\Gamma{(\alpha+1)}\Gamma{(\alpha)}}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)^{\alpha-1} s^{\alpha} \rm{d}s = t^{2\alpha} \int_{0}^{1} (1-u)^{\alpha-1}u^{\alpha}\rm{d}u = t^{2\alpha} \beta(\alpha+1,\alpha) = \frac{t^{2\alpha}}{\Gamma(2\alpha+1)}$. But how to solve  $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)^{\alpha-1} (1-s)^{\alpha} \rm{d}s$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. can you show your work?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: In general to calculate: 
$$\int_{a}^{t}{{{(t-s)}^{\alpha -1}}{{(s-a)}^{\beta }}ds}$$
use 
$$s=a+u\left( t-a \right)$$

Comment: @Pandi: I notice that in the original problem, before the edits, it was assume that $0<t<1$ and $0<\alpha<1$. Does that still hold?

Comment: yes. Sorry I forget to mention that.